# View SSRS report using reportViewer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to display SSRS report in my asp.net web application using reportViewer control.

SSRS report is deployed on the cloud and  i am using following code

```
 <div>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download PDF"  onClick="btnDownload_Click" />

      </div>
      <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer"  runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

//Server Side code

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl =new Uri("https://vvlt38yf7h.reporting.windows.net/reportserver");
            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Test/Report_Demo";
            rptViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            rptViewer.ShowPrintButton = true;
            rptViewer.ShowExportControls = false;

        }
```

It shows the following error

Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message

Comment: May be Report Server is Returning Error Message in Text/Html Format (Error messages Always returns as Text/Html, may be the authentication problem you have got) but, your ReportViewer Expect data in text/xml format. Thats the Issue. Use Firebug and See whats the error is throwing for that request from the Report server and Post. Then we could help. Hope you got.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check if your service is up and running.

see here http://forums.asp.net/t/1411427.aspx/1